How can I increase QR code resolution scannability for a react native app?
I'm have a QR code scanning issue as of late and am looking for a solution or insights.
The problem:
After some changes, the text content of a QR code generation increased from ~1000 characters to 3000+. After this change, the resolution required to read the QR code increased, which rendered some particular app libraries on Android (within a React Native app) useless.
Caveats:

The size of data within the QR code text cannot be compressed any further
The QR code cannot be split into two or more and thereafter be concatenated (for UX purposes)
The QR code scans with ease on iOS, and even the standard Android
camera, however it fails to scan with most React native library
camera kits.

Here is a list of libraries and versions I've tried which all fail to scan the QR code.
Tested and does not work:

react-native-camera-kit (latest version)
Latest version of Google ML kit scanner (Android + Google Play version)
react-native-vision-camera

The Android SDK version is 31 using JDK 11 and Gradle 6.7, and React Native 0.68.
The camera simply does not recognize a code so large in its current state.
Any advice or recommendation is much appreciated.

That is a very large QR code, though within limits.  I recommend you reconsider "The size of data within the QR code text cannot be compressed any further".  If you describe the flow (how is the code created, what happens after you scan it?), we can suggest alternate solutions (e.g. URL shorteners, caches, etc.).  Dense QR codes like that are not very user-friendly, and as you're seeing, scanning them can be difficult.
